# Safe to delete these files? (sockets.log & libpeerconnection.log)

Tags: macos

These files are listed in my user directory.
Can I delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both log files made for debugging purposes. Google Chrome/Chromium makes the libpeerconnection.log (https://superuser.com/questions/627903/what-is-the-file-libpeerconnection-log) and the sockets.log one is made by uTorrent (https://discussions.apple.com/message/20543713).

They can both be deleted with no problems -- just be aware that the programs that made them might keep remaking them.

Comment: thanks that was what I wanted to know!